# Is asking about the existence of a soundtrack considered a "game rec"?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

My question, [Who composed the soundtrack for the Tangled video game?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/235879/was-a-soundtrack-sold-for-the-tangled-video-game)

First off, I knew it was a gamble asking since it's mildly peripheral to the video game itself, and it came close to asking for shopping advice, but I feel like, at the least the reason for closing is terribly inaccurate. Is it simply a matter of that the first person voted for closure because they thought it sounded like a game recommendation and then everyone else said, "Eh, close enough"? Secondly, well, I feel like it's a question with a definite answer that's on the topic of games. I didn't ask where to find the best deal, or what's the best soundtrack to buy. I simply asked whether the soundtrack for the game was available for sale, something which does not seem to be among the *verboten* topics in the Tour.

So, is this something that cannot be asked about here?

Comment: I voted to close this question not because it was directly a recommendation question, but because of the underlying request for how to access the music. Once you have the names of the songs (quite easy to find out with user research), there are many ways you can obtain the music. Do you go to a music store? Maybe you can go on iTunes. Maybe you grab the music from the game, itself, or just use a sound recorder. Asking how to access the music is a recommendation request, as there are many ways to access music, and the answers will often result from that users opinion, or 'recommendation'.

Comment: That said, I would recommend checking out the credits (the official music listing will be there - song name, composer, etc.). From there, I would try checking iTunes.

Comment: @Timelord64 - see my comment about the composer on the question :-)

Comment: I don't see any reason why your question was considered to be asking for a recommendation.  If I had 3000 reputation I would vote to re-open.  Sometimes questions just get eaten around here and unfortunately you really can't do anything about it.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't seem to be a shopping recommendation as defined by [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/), linked in the close reason. Close Voters probably saw the words "sold" and "purchasing" and assumed that was the case.

I originally thought as much myself, it wasn't until a second read-through that I realised it was simply asking if the soundtrack was available, at all. Which is nice, because a  similar situation actually came up in this meta question:

[Asking if a game-related-product is available, at all, anywhere, for anyone](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8389/28182)

Whilst the community seems split on the issue, the question that spawned that discussion remains open, although still with a negative vote score.

Based how that meta question played out, and the fact that I disagree that your question is a 'Shopping recommendation', I have voted to reopen it.

---

Note however, I believe the question would be better received if it were reworded to something like:

> Who composed the soundtrack for the Tangled Video Game?

This way, the answer won't change or become obsolete with time. Even if the album gets taken down, people will still be able to find it.

Comment: I am looking to ask a particular question along the lines of "was [x] ever released" but have so far avoided because of the "game rec" definition.  Its an old game that I am looking for in a particular version (specific colour mode and language=English).  I have screenshots to suggest it existed (and some research to provide) but it could also be a modded version.  The only other way I can think of rewording the question is as a game identification question.  I know this is a different problem than the OP gave but both are caused by not being able to ask "was [x] ever released?".

Comment: @CamelCase - if you have screenshots, then you should just be able to ask it as a game identification question without too much hassle

Comment: I have modified the question if you want to provide that answer. On a side note, I also realized that I erred. I've been playing Brave and Tangled in pretty close succession and it got confused in my head. Any idea as to who did the music in the Brave video game? It's not on WIkipedia.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - Cool. I have added my comment as an answer on your question. As for Brave, I will see if I can find out tomorrow (it's currently 1am here) :-)

Comment: @Sean - I was unable to find any info online about Brave's soundtrack, however, give me a week or so - I submitted a support ticket to Disney interactive asking who composed it and/or if it were available for purchase/listening online. Let's see if we get a response :-)

Comment: @SeanDuggan - I have your answer :) - would you like to pose it as a question?

Comment: Added: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/236622/who-composed-the-soundtrack-for-the-brave-wii-game

Comment: Adding this here as well before I forget again, as the type of question they are asking about there is relevant to this one: [Are trivial questions allowed on the site?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/a/7571/28182)

Answer (score 3):

Based on the fact that 
[What is available for vintage game download on Wii?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10810/what-is-available-for-vintage-game-download-on-wii?rq=1) is apparently a valid question, and asking "Does x exist" is clearly different than asking "What should I buy", I think your questions is allowable.  At least, I haven't seen evidence that shows otherwise.